# Twitter bootstrap collapse - icons with :after

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using :after to have the icons for the header and everything is pretty self-explanatory until I want to switch between them.
I made this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/73C9v/

Because stackoverflow wants me to and because this is the only custom code:

```
.accordion-toggle:after {
    content: 'ON';
}
.accordion-toggle.collapsed:after {
    content: 'OFF';
}
```

You can see the problem when you click on one and then when it opens, the other one. By clicking another accordion. The :after doesn't change, meaning the icons won't change if I have them there.

What is the best way to do this? I haven't seen an issue like this with using :before/:after, so I'm looking for a solution that is as elegant as possible.

E: I am using Bootstrap v2.3.2

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't anything special, I just did this:

```
$('.accordion-toggle').on('click', function(){
    $('.accordion-toggle').not(this).addClass('collapsed');
});
```

Not sure why this doesn't happen by default :-(